# Relacionamento 1:N no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, entity-framework

Boa tarde.
Eu estou estudando o EntityFramework e não estou conseguindo fazer uma coisa que parece ser simples, mas não vai. :(
Eu queria fazer um relacionamento 1:N entre uma tabela para um cliente que pode ter várias cotações, porém as cotações só podem ter um cliente.

Está é a minha classe Cliente:

```
public class Cliente
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double CPF { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    //public Cotacao Cotacao { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Cotacao> Cotacao { get; set; }
    //public virtual IEnumerable<Cotacao> Cotacoes { get; set; }

    public Cliente(double cpf, string nome, ICollection<Cotacao> cotacao)
    {
        CPF = cpf;
        Nome = nome ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nome));
        Cotacao = cotacao ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cotacao));
    }

    public Cliente(double cpf, string nome)
    {
        CPF = cpf;
        Nome = nome ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nome));
    }
}
```

Está é a minha classe Cotação:

```
public class Cotacao
{   
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Idade { get; set; }
    public string Genero { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
    public string AnoModelo { get; set; }


    public Cotacao(Cliente cliente, string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
    {
        Cliente = cliente;
        Idade = idade;
        Genero = genero;
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        AnoModelo = anoModelo;

    }

    public Cotacao(string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
    {
        Idade = idade;
        Genero = genero;
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        AnoModelo = anoModelo;
    }
}
```

Esse é o meu Contexto:

```
public partial class ContextDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cotacao> Cotacoes { get; set; }

    public ContextDB() : base("name=ContextDB")
    {

    }
}
```

E é assim que eu estou criando salvando os dados no banco:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpf))
        {
            using (var ctx = new ContextDB())
            {
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(double.Parse(cpf), nome);
                Cotacao cotacao = new Cotacao(cliente, idade, genero, marca, modelo, anoFabricacao, anoModelo);


                if (cliente.CPF == cotacao.Cliente.CPF) // Sem esse if, também não vai.
                {
                    ctx.Cotacoes.Add(cotacao);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                else
                {
                    ctx.Clientes.Add(cliente);
                    ctx.Cotacoes.Add(cotacao);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Mas toda vez ele cria um cliente novo e não associa o contrato ao cliente.
[image: Os Contratos]

[image: Os Clientes]

Imagino que o problemas está em criar dois objetos, porém eu não sei como eu faria para adicionar um objeto já existente na criação do outro.
O que eu estaria fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua classe Cotação tem um relacionamento com cliente, então você precisa especificar o campo de chave estrangeira nela que será relacionado com cliente, que geralmente usa-se `ClienteId`, más não é necessário ser este nome.

Então na sua classe deixe ela deste jeito

```cs
public class Cotacao
{   
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ClienteId {get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    public string Idade { get; set; }
    public string Genero { get; set; }
    public string Marca { get; set; }
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    public string AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
    public string AnoModelo { get; set; }


    public Cotacao(Cliente cliente, string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
    {
        Cliente = cliente;
        Idade = idade;
        Genero = genero;
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        AnoModelo = anoModelo;

    }

    public Cotacao(string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
    {
        Idade = idade;
        Genero = genero;
        Marca = marca;
        Modelo = modelo;
        AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
        AnoModelo = anoModelo;
    }
}
```

Assim sua classe terá um relacionamento de 1:N com a classe de clientes.

-> Edição abaixo

Repliquei seu código na minha maquina aqui e fiz uns teste, e ficou deste jeito aqui, e funcionou consegui criar clientes e cotações para esses clietes, e também trazendo as cotações na busca dos clientes.

Classe Cliente

```
public class Cliente
     {
        [Key()]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CPF { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Cotacao> Cotacao { get; set; }

        public Cliente(string cpf, string nome, ICollection<Cotacao> cotacao)
        {
            CPF = cpf;
            Nome = nome ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nome));
            Cotacao = cotacao ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cotacao));
        }

        public Cliente(string cpf, string nome)
        {
            CPF = cpf;
            Nome = nome ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(nome));
        }

        public Cliente()
        {
        }
    }
```

- Primeiramente coloquei as configurações de banco via FluenteAPI na classe ContexDB e também troquei o tipo da propriedade `CPF` para `string`, não é obrigatório porém para faz mais sentido o cpf ser string.

Classe Cotação

```
public class Cotacao
    {
        [Key()]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Idade { get; set; }
        public string Genero { get; set; }
        public string Marca { get; set; }
        public string Modelo { get; set; }
        public string AnoFabricacao { get; set; }
        public string AnoModelo { get; set; }
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

        public Cotacao()
        {

        }

        public Cotacao(Cliente cliente, string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
        {
            Cliente = cliente;
            Idade = idade;
            Genero = genero;
            Marca = marca;
            Modelo = modelo;
            AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
            AnoModelo = anoModelo;

        }

        public Cotacao(string idade, string genero, string marca, string modelo, string anoFabricacao, string anoModelo)
        {
            Idade = idade;
            Genero = genero;
            Marca = marca;
            Modelo = modelo;
            AnoFabricacao = anoFabricacao;
            AnoModelo = anoModelo;
        }
    }
```

Na classe Cotação criei uma construtor vazio, pois nas consultas o entity precisa de um construtor vazio.

Classe ContexDB

```
public partial class ContextDB : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Cliente> Clientes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cotacao> Cotacoes { get; set; }

        public ContextDB() : base("name=ContextDB")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Cotacao>().HasRequired(c => c.Cliente).WithMany(c => c.Cotacao);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Configurei os relacionamentos com FluenteAPI, sobreescrevendo o método `OnModelCreating`.

Então criei dois objetos clientes e adicionei na base, depois criei s objetos de cotação e adicionei aos clientes através da propriedade ClienteId.

```
using (var db = new ContextDB())
            {
                //Cria os objetos dos clientes
                var cliente1 = new Cliente("12345678912", "Robson Silva Brito");
                var cliente2 = new Cliente("65415935745", "Eliane Moraes");

                //Adiciona os objetos para inserção
                db.Clientes.Add(cliente1);
                db.Clientes.Add(cliente2);

                //Salva no banco
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Cria os objetos de cotação
                var cotacao1 = new Cotacao("15", "Masculino", "Chevrolet", "Agile", "2011", "2011");
                //Atribuo esse objeto a um cliente com o Id do cliente
                cotacao1.ClienteId = 1;

                var cotacao2 = new Cotacao("25", "Masculino", "Chevrolet", "Corsa", "2011", "2011");
                cotacao2.ClienteId = 2;

                //Adiciona as instancia para inserção
                db.Cotacoes.Add(cotacao1);
                db.Cotacoes.Add(cotacao2);
                //Salva no banco
                db.SaveChanges();

                //Traz todos clientes junto com suas cotações
                var clientes = db.Clientes.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: Olá Robson, obrigado pela ajuda, porém continuo com o mesmo problema.
Ainda são gerados novos cadastros do mesmo cliente e as cotações continuam sendo criadas com esses Id dos clientes "novos", você teria mais alguma dica do que pode estar errado?

Comment: R.Souza editei a resposta lá, funcionou certinho nos testes que fiz aqui. Veja se funciona pra você também.

Comment: Caso você queira deixar a propriedade __ClienteId__ sendo passado no construtor também só adicionar ela junto em algum dos construtores, e não apague a opção de construtor vazio, caso contrario na hora de trazer os dados você não vai conseguir.

Comment: Robson, obrigado pela ajuda, realmente funcionou conforme você mostrou.
Adicionei as informações que você me passou e procurei sobre o FluentAPI, me ajudou muito.
E usei as informações desse link [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/ef6/querying/) para procurar a primeira pessoa no banco com o ID/CPF que entra como informação.

Muito obrigado novamente, eu sabia que estava errando em algumas coisas, mas vou procurar estudar mais para entender tudo do Entity, abraços.

Comment: Isso ai cara, que bom que funcionou. O entity realmente é muito bom e dominalo te dará uma boa vantagem nas construções de suas aplicações. Flw bom estudo aí.